# Access Modifiers - Should be loaded only once

Tags: c#, oop

Can We prevent the following from loading more than once in my application. ie any other alternative than this?

```
public IEnumerable<User> users()
{
    var users = Userlist();
    return users.ToList();
}

public static List<User> Userlist()
{
    string strSQL = "";
    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    strSQL = "select USERID,USERNAME,PASSWORD from USERS";

    //if (Userlist().Count > 0)
    //{
    //    return Userlist();
    //}
    //else
    //{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(strSQL, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    users.Add(new User { Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["USERID"]), user = dataReader["USERNAME"].ToString(), password = Decrypt(dataReader["PASSWORD"].ToString()), estatus = true, RememberMe = true });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return users;
    // }
}
```

I just wanted the solution to be like the **commented part**(which does not work here).

**EDIT :**  I just wanted to avoid unnecessary database calls.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You will have to store the contents of your list at some point in your application, otherwise your list to check will always be empty. You can use a static field in your class though, so your static method will access that static field, so the information is only stored once.

Comment: `"select USERID,USERNAME,PASSWORD from USERS"` sends cold shivers to the core of my soul; have we (the collective programmer community) not learned never to store passwords, yet?

Comment: @MarcGravell Well it might be (I hope) the salted password hash that is stored there and that this list is actually used to authenticate the users. Otherwise yes it is one of those holy f*** moments.

Comment: @Adwaenyth you saw the word `Decrypt`, right? Yeah, it is one of those moments

Comment: Perhaps a better question here: how many *logins per second* are you expecting that it makes sense to hoist this data into in-process memory? I can't think of any realistic scenario where it would be a genuine bottleneck, in which case: leave it at the database. In fact, on any given day, *most* of your users *won't log in*, so: why have everyone in memory? Only go to the DB for the few that *do* log in, with a single-row `where`-based query

Answer (score 3):

The usual trick is to lazily load them. You could just use a `Lazy<T>`, but a double-checked simple field works too:

```
static List<Foo> fetched;
static readonly object syncLock = new object(); // because: threading
public static List<Foo> Whatever {
    get {
        var tmp = fetched;
        if(tmp != null) return tmp;
        lock(syncLock) {
            tmp = fetched;
            if(tmp != null) return tmp; // double-checked lock
            return fetched = GetTheActualData();
        }
    }
}
private static List<Foo> GetTheActualData() {...}
```

Additional thoughts:

- storing passwords is **never a good idea**
- `List<T>` is mutable; you should make sure people can't change the list or the items in the list if you are storing it statically
- what do you do when the data changes at the database? how does it update?

Comment: Thanks. This is just a sample code. Are there any article regarding managing passwords so that I could get a clear idea?

Comment: I am encrypting the password before storing :)
**Decrypt(dataReader["PASSWORD"].ToString()) **

Comment: @Ruban.J which means you are doing it wrong. One does not encrypt passwords (unless you are writing a password manager tool like 1pass). One *hashes* passwords. If you (or your software) is *even remotely capable* of decrypting them: you've done it horribly horribly wrong. You don't need to know the actual password to check a password.

Comment: Thanks @Marc . Are there any sampl code Snippets for these available?

Comment: @Ruban.J Go add yourself to the http://plaintextoffenders.com/ list. Because encrypting your password is the same as putting it in plaintext.

Comment: @Ruban.J the site I linked to covers more than I can cover here.

Comment: @Ruban.J No there are not sample code snippets, because even hashing is wrong. One uses a library that handles your security (one that salts then hashes, then peppers and finally roasts it til its golden brown). http://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: @Aron I agree that is probably the best bet for someone who is new to the area, but it is certainly a bit more nuanced than that in more complex systems

Comment: Regarding "thought" bullet two, you can declare `fetched` as a `IReadOnlyList<Foo>` (for example), and then use `fetched = GetTheActualData().AsReadOnly()` when you assign to it. Of course this does not assure that each `Foo` instance is immutable in itself, that should be the case in addition.

Comment: I wonder if it is better to mark the `fetched` field as `volatile` or not, given that you check it for `null` from many threads both before and after the `lock`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen no need; the lock and double-check deals with all that. The only interesting values are null or not-null. In the not-null case, that's all we need. In the null case: the memory barrier (from the lock) does what we need.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen agree that a `.AsReadOnly()` (from the list) would be a good idea - basically any kind of immutable collection.

Answer (score 0):

Use Lazy, it is thread safe. [Lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private Lazy<IEnumerable<User>> users = new Lazy<IEnumerable<User>>(Userlist);
public Lazy<IEnumerable<User>> Users
{
  get
  {
    return this.users;
  }
}

public static IEnumerable<User> Userlist()
{
    string strSQL = "";
    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    strSQL = "select USERID,USERNAME,PASSWORD from USERS";

    //if (Userlist().Count > 0)
    //{
    //    return Userlist();
    //}
    //else
    //{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(strSQL, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    users.Add(new User { Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["USERID"]), user = dataReader["USERNAME"].ToString(), password = Decrypt(dataReader["PASSWORD"].ToString()), estatus = true, RememberMe = true });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return users;
    // }
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error like this 
'(()=>Userlist)' - Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: @Ruban.J Updated the answer, it should be ok now. Consider making the initialization async because now the first call will block the calling thread while it is loading the users from the db.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `caching` for this.

The idea is that, the `List<Users>` will be cached, and any time when applications asks for the user list, we return it from the cache, and avoiding the database hit thereof.

A sample implementation could be something like this. Suggest to read more about caching, as there are many aspects that needs to taken care like, when the cache will expire, how it will get invalidate if new users are entered in database etc.

```
public List<User> Userlist()
        {
            ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

            var users = cache["users"];

            if (users == null)
            {
                CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();

                //For dmonstration, I used cache expring after 1 day
                //Set the cache policy as per your need
                policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);


                // Fetch the users here from database
                List<User> userList = GetUsersFromDatabase();

                //Set the users in the cache
                cache.Set("users", userList, policy);

            }

            return cache["users"] as List<User>;
        }

        private static List<User> GetUsersFromDatabase()
        {
            string strSQL = "";
            List<User> users = new List<User>();
            strSQL = "select USERID,USERNAME,PASSWORD from USERS";

            //if (Userlist().Count > 0)
            //{
            //    return Userlist();
            //}
            //else
            //{
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(strSQL, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            users.Add(new User { Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["USERID"]), user = dataReader["USERNAME"].ToString(), password = Decrypt(dataReader["PASSWORD"].ToString()), estatus = true, RememberMe = true });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return users;
        }
```